# Setting chartingToolkit:PieSeries style in WPF xaml code

Tags: wpf, xaml, graph, charts, pie-chart

I'm trying to control the style of the `ChartArea` and the `Legend` of a piechart with XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Pie Chart Style -->
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:Chart">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="LegendStyle" Value="0" />            
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:PieSeries" x:Key="SpecialStyle">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

    <chartingToolkit:Chart Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Name="resultsChartData" Title="Results Chart" BorderThickness="0">
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource SpecialStyle}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

A few issues confuse me:

1) I can manipulate the `BorderThickness` of the `:Chart`, but if I try the same in the `:PieSeries` it has no effect. So I've tried applying `Styles`, but that has no effect either. What am I doing wrong?

2) I also want to manipulate the `Legend` graphics, and there's a `Property` called `LegendStyle` that I can apply, but I don't know which values can be input here.. Do I refer to another `Style` somehow? Since the `:Legend` isn't a `TargetType`, at least from the setup of the `Chart` code, I can't create a separate `Style` for it specifically.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this were resolved?

Comment: No, in the end I am using a completely different method to achieve this